# can i load local CSS file when loading a specific webpage from the internet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, .htaccess, vhosts

my question is pretty much direct.

i just want to customize the **css** of a site that im accessing from my local PC(currently using firebug to change it temporarily).

i want to load an extra **css** file for that website(only on my PC).

i been wondering about this for long, do you have any idea how can this be achieved?

for example if the `site` has a code:

```
body{
   background:blue;
}
```

i want it to use:

```
body{
   background:red !important;
}
```

every-time i load that website.

Comment: There are browser extensions for this purpose

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: You could always use PHP's `if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] === '127.0.0.1'){echo "@import 'custompage.css';"}`. Of course, you would echo this inside of a `<style type='text/css'></style>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, then you can use *Stylish*. It's an extension for both. It may be under the name 'UserStyles' as well. It's relatively simple to use; you just need to install it and add in your personal styles.
[Chrome Version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en)
[Firefox Version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish something like this with a browser extension. Search for 'browser extension' along with the browser you want to implement it for.

Answer (score 1):

Use an extensions like stylish or userscript/greasemonkey